# Why won't gam.check run for my simple model? Error in xy.coords

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am trying to run different gam models using the mgcv package to predict animal behaviour based on time of day and latitude. My data frame has a 0/1 column that states whether an animal was detected at that specific time and latitude.

```
gam1 <- gam(ANI~s(Lat) + s(Time), family="binomial", data=mydata
```

My model runs without a problem but when I try to run gam.check() I get this error:
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
When I run the code I get a QQ plot, but nothing else.

I tried running a different model from the same data frame, but still run into the issue. Is there a problem with the way I set up the model? Could it be my data frame? Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I'd also confirm that you only have the mgcv package loaded (and not the gam package), so try to run your example in a clean environment loading only the minimal set of required packages for the data and the GAM. Also, make sure you are running a recent version of R and that mgcv is up to date.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I restarted R and started with a clean environment and it worked like a charm! Thanks!